# Are y-coordinates of a random polynomial distributed uniformly at random?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, polynomials

Hypothesis: All operations and values are defined over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a large prime number, e.g., $128$-bit. Everyone knows the description of this field. For simplicity let's assume the values are not zero.

---

My question is related to cryptography and in particular "Shamir secret sharing" [scheme](http://web.mit.edu/6.857/OldStuff/Fall03/ref/Shamir-HowToShareASecret.pdf).

- Let polynomial $p(x)$ be of degree $t$ whose coeffients are picked uniformly at random from $\mathbb{F}_p$.
- Let $ X=\{x_1,...,x_{t+1}\}$ be random non-zero distinct elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$.
- Let $Z$ be a subset of $X$ (i.e. $Z\subset X$) and its size is smaller than $X$.

---

- We evaluate $p(x)$ at each element of Z, this gives us the y-coordinates, $Y=\{y_1,...,y_t\}$.
- We set $K=\{k_1,...,k_t\}$, where each $k_i$ is picked uniformly at random from $\mathbb{F}_p$.

**Question**: Given (1) the polynomial's degree, (2) $E=\{(x_1,y_1),...(x_t,y_t)\}$, and (3) $K=\{k_1,...,k_t\}$, can someone distinguishe each y-coordinate in $E$ from each element in $K$ with a non-negligible probability?

Comment: Your question is not well posed. As long as $t$ is not huge, none of the $y_i$ equal any of the $k_j$, and given distinct elements from a finite field, the probability that somebody can distinguish them is $1$. But that does not seem to be what you are asking about.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen sure I'm happy to improve the question. First, let me understand your comment.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen If I understand you correctly, you're saying that because $y_i$ values are not equal to $k_i$ values, then someone can distinguish $y_i$ values from $k_i$ values. If that's the case, then why (or how) it can distinguish them?

Comment: I simply mean that you are not saying what you mean when you ask whether someone can distinguish the outcomes. If one flips three (different) coins two times in succession, and the outcomes are say HTT and HTH, the somebody can distinguish the outcomes since, well HTT and HTH are different, its easy. What you want to ask is whether the _probability distributions_ for the outcomes are the same for the two processes, and that is quite a different question

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen thanks for the comment, the end of the question says "with a non-negligible probability". Don't you think it would suffice?